# how to output from php code of view to basic page using drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I have a field in the view where I have written PHP code for it. I am using View PHP module for that. Inside PHP code I have a button, onclick of that button, it goes to a basic page.

**Question:** I need to pass the values from the view to basic page.

I used $_POST and $_GET, they are not working. I used $_SESSION, before exit I have unset the session variabls. The view is in many pages.  the value displays for one session of the page but the other its not.

Please help me, it very important and critical...
thanks for help in advance

Comment: are you set a button as a link like this 
l('Link Text', 'news', array('query' => array('pid' => '3'));

Comment: I can get the value of the fields through field_view_value(), I am able to display the same in the view, but not able to transfer to another page